# Alternatives to Model-Based Feature Selection for Unsupervised Clustering

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, feature-engineering, preprocessing, unsupervised-learning

I am running a clustering model on a group of patients who are hypertensive with hopes of identifying different variations in clinical characteristics among hypertensive individuals.

One of the issues I currently have is that I initially filtered out all of the non-hypertensive patients and then preprocessed.

I planned to use a random-forest model with Hypertension being my response variable to select the top 10 features and then run unsupervised clustering. However, I now realize that this is not possible since my non-hypertensive patients are no longer in the dataset.

Are there any better way to go about selecting more important variables in my scenario?

Comment: Why must you do any feature selection at all? Typically you cluster based on variables that you are interested in discovering patterns for, you don't nornally do feature selection because the idea is that you are only including the variables that align with your analysis objectives.